# Conditionally authenticate users to DRF view

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, api-design

I have a DRF view as such:

```
class DocumentsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()
    # I typically enforce authentication with 
    # authentication_classes = (JWTCookieAuthentication,)

    def list(self, request):
        pagination_class = None
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated: 
           ... return protected data ...
        else:
           ... return generic data ...
```

I want to allow both users sending a valid token and those not sending a valid token to both get a response from this endpoint. However, `request.user.is_authenticated` returns `False`, even when a valid token is sent (I understand why). How can I try to authenticate the user, but still allow them to proceed even if not presenting a token?

Or is better practice to not have the same view to authenticated an unauthenticated users?

Comment: *However, request.user.is_authenticated returns False, even when a valid token is sent (I understand why).* I don't. Does the authentication backend not log the user in or is the authentication middleware not running?

Comment: @Melvyn, because authentication_classes = () in the view overrides my DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to have **no permissions**, but still *perform authentication*.

Authentication validates tokens, gets the user from the database, etc.  If you disable it, then no checks of tokens/etc will be performed. This means `request.user` will always equal `AnonymousUser`.

```
class MyView(ListCreateApiView):
    permissions_classes = [AllowAny]
```

It's worth considering using `AllowAny` as your permission.  It is the same as using a blank list `[]`, but makes it clear your intention is to make the view public, rather than a mistake.